# FQL when logged out

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible to query using Facebook Query Language when not currently logged in as a Facebook user? I'm trying to simply query when the user isn't logged in, so I can return their name, but instead of throwing up any errors, it just returns a response but the fields are blank.

Any ideas why this occurs, or do I need to look at storing the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to query these values when the user is not logged in.

Comment: Are you sure? Even if the application has the "offline_access" Extended Permission and is working with an application access token, instead of a user access token?